# Python ElementTree parsing unbound prefix error

Tags: python, xml, prefix, elementtree

I am learning ElementTree in python. Everything seems fine except when I try to parse the xml file with prefix:

`test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc:data>
   <abc:country name="Liechtenstein" rank="1" year="2008">
   </abc:country>
   <abc:country name="Singapore" rank="4" year="2011">
   </abc:country>
   <abc:country name="Panama" rank="5" year="2011">
   </abc:country>
</abc:data>
```

When I try to parse the xml:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
```

I got the following error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 2, column 0
```

Do I need to specify something in order to parse a xml file with prefix?

Comment: in short you have a missing namespace for abc. take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4999510/1107807

Answer (score 23):

Add the abc namespace to your xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc:data xmlns:abc="your namespace">
```

Comment: But what about when it's not my XML to change, I just need to parse it?

Comment: I second the question/comment from @Mark Allen! I am having the same problem. Certainly on a case-by-case basis one could edit the file, but I have many large (and nonuniform) xml files. Surely there is a way to get around this

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_file = "test.xml"

with open(xml_file, "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "xml")

    items = soup.find_all("country")
    print (items)
```

The above will produce an array which you can then manipulate to achieve your aim (e.g. remove html tags etc.):

> ```
> [<country name="Liechtenstein" rank="1" year="2008">
> </country>, <country name="Singapore" rank="4" year="2011">
> </country>, <country name="Panama" rank="5" year="2011">
> </country>]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while processing xml file. You can use below code before parse your XML file. This will resolve your issue.

```
parser1 = etree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8", recover=True)
tree1 = ElementTree.parse('filename.xml', parser1)
```

Comment: The `recover` option works with lxml, but not with the built-in ElementTree library.