# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: How to solve this issue without making any change to xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

This is my sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NewSpg>
     <!--Supported Range-->

<ABC data="LS">
   <number Info="0x00" Id="DFS" Bus="0" Device="2" Range="4" Value="0x1A1012f5" no_id="he d kd" /> 
          <number Info="0x32" Id="bhi"  Range="4" Value="0x000012f5" />
          <number Info="0x336" Id="bhi" Range="4" Value="0x00000df2" />
</ABC>
<!--New Info-->
   <NEW_VALUES>
         <Spg:Thing data="First_Thing" Result="true"/>
         <Spg:Thing data="SecondThing" Result="800000000"/>
   </NEW_VALUES>

</NewSpg>
```

when i try to parse the xml:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_file = "name.xml"
xml_tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = xml_tree.getroot()
```

Following Error occured:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 13, column 9
```

I have referred many sites but most of them gives only one solution i.e to provide namespace. But I can't add or delete anything in this xml file. So is there any method by which i can parse this xml file without modifying the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372604/python-elementtree-parsing-unbound-prefix-error

Comment: I have referred this one but the problem is i can't modify my xml file by adding namespace and the second solution provided there requires lxml .

Comment: you could read in the file as a string make the edit to the namespace and then parse the file with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647071/python-xml-elementtree-from-a-string-source that is an option though a strange workaround. don't know if there is something cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope, this will fix your issue (use lxml ETREE)

```
from lxml import etree
xml_file = "./unbound_prefix.xml"
parser1 = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8', recover=True)
xml_tree = etree.parse(xml_file, parser=parser1)
root = xml_tree.getroot()
root
```

Comment: I have tried this method but im not able to install lxml.

Comment: when i try to install lxml it is getting timed out.

Comment: pip --default-timeout=1000 install lxml #(if default-timout not works try with --timeout) this is an network slowness problem

Comment: i tried this both method in my other laptop. But in that it's not working.

Comment: there Is some network connection problem it is out of control of pip.

Comment: i'am connected to vpn will that be the cause of this issue.

Comment: try to disconnect with vpn and then install with it with another network connection