# Delete a specific part of a file python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I work under python 3.2 on Windows (8.1), and I have an XML file in which I would like to delete a specific part if this one exists. Here is the visual example of what I need to do:

[image: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img905/8028/9DAu6v.png]

I would like to know how we could delete the selected part in the picture, knowing that there can be or not several occurences of .

Comment: What you really want is an XML parser. Parse your input XML using one of the many libraries out there (start using https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), work with the resulting internal representation, modify it, and write a new XML file to your disk.

Comment: I’m taking a look at it~

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml.etree.ElementTree: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('file.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

root = tree.getroot()
for node in root.iter():
    if node.tag == 'object2':
        root.remove(node)

tree.write(out.xml)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to understand how I could effectively use it. But alas, it seems that my file doesn’t fit the standard XML form, as I got this result (I had to censor some parts of the file, but not important parts):
http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9097/CDI9DK.png

Here is the aspect of the file behore (I think it’ll be easier to answer with this image):
http://imageshack.com/a/img905/8028/9DAu6v.png
It also deleted some data from the file that is needed.

Comment: Its hard to understand what has changed in the images. Can you explain a bit better what is wrong.

Comment: Well, the four original lines were merged into one, almost all the data which is colored in yellow in the original code has been lost, only a few data remains (such as the <version><![CDATA[4.0.0.3]]></version> line 6 which became <ns0:version>4.0.0.3</ns0:version> line 3), and there is this “ns0:” added everywhere

Comment: The ns0: is added by default if you don't specify the namespace (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997848/emitting-namespace-specifications-with-elementtree-in-python). The CDATA disapears because ElementTree does not have support for that. You can find ways to make ElementTree support CDATA (see https://gist.github.com/zlalanne/5711847)

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
f=open("some.xml",'r')
f.close()
x=f.read()
y=re.sub(r"<object2>(?:(?!<\/object2>)[\s\S])*<\/object2>","",x)
f=open("some.xml",'w')
f.write(y)
f.close()
```

You can try this using `re`.

Comment: Well, this doesn’t actually work, I get this error: http://gyazo.com/a119c6f858dcf601609bb9d8326f44d9

Comment: (just noticed I made a little mistake when editing the code, but once fixed it didn’t change the result)

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open('xmlfile.xml','r')
flag = False
tempData = ''
for line in f:
  if '<object2>' in line:
    flag = True
  elif flag == True and '</object2>' in line:
    flag = False
  elif flag == False:
    tempData += line
f.close()
f = open('xmlfile.xml','w')
f.write(tempData)
f.close()
```

A little longer than vks' answer, but it does not require an import.

Comment: Well, it partially works, the part I wanted to remove has been removed, but so does the rest of the document ^^

Comment: I forgot to put () on the end of f.close(), and .readline() is assumed in the 'for' loop. These have now been correced. Tested the code and it is working perfectly now. Sorry for posting code before it was tested.